# how to bind to an openldap server

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I am using the PHP extension.
The username is admin
password is 111111
I try to bind using `ldap_bind($rs,'admin','111111')`
It gives me an error:

> Unable to bind to server: Invalid DN
>   syntax in [line of the ldap_bind]

I can bind anonymously, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: The problem might actually be with your `ldap_connect` call (quoting http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php ) : *When OpenLDAP 2.x.x is used, ldap_connect() will always return a resource as it does not actually connect but just initializes the connecting parameters. The actual connect happens with the next calls to ldap_ funcs, usually with ldap_bind().*

Comment: That is why I pointed out I can bind anonymously, i.e. without the credentials.

Answer (score 2):

OK - my bad, I should have used the entire record name instead of just admin: `"cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"` which describes the top node in the server.